# Why I can't use Ti namespace with a TideSDK project with TiDev Community App

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I am using TideSDK Developer to create a new desktop app. I'm not sure of the differences between "TideSDK Developer" and "TiDev Community 1.3.03"?

I develop with php language. But I can't use **Ti** in my project.

Answer (score 3):

TideSDK Developer was stripped down from TiDev Community 1.3. TiDev community is not compatible with TideSDK and you cannot use it with code using the 'Ti' namespace.
Your only choice is to use TideSDK Developer. You must change the namespace on any API reference in a project created using the older TiDev Community to 'Ti' for TideSDK Developer to build the project.

Keep in mind TideKit is releasing soon with a new CLI, app and will provide platform builds. You can follow recent developments at http://www.tidekit.com. The video of what is coming is here: http://youtu.be/aE7gN-d0GhU. This will give you modern tools to use where the experience of creating and your projects is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Like in any other programming language, there are reserved words that cannot be used, and in the case of TideKit/TideSDK Ti is one of them. Probably you can rename your variable with another suitable name, instead using a reserved word.